changing a dataframe value based on a unique row value
a bit new to pandas and looking for a possibly better way to solve the following:
given a df where I know a unique value (bb) in a column (A) I want to change the value found in another column (C)
the solution, which I think seems a bit complicated is as follows:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
                   "B":[1, 1, 1],
                   "C":[1, 88, 1],
                   "D":[1, 1, 1]})

print(df, '\n')

df.at[int(df.loc[df['A']=='bb', 'C'].index.values), 'C'] = 1

print(df)

but I guess there is a simpler way to achieve this?
I guess as this seems quite a basic need that I had hoped to find something more like :
df.at_or_something_else['A'=='bb', 'C']


df.loc[df['A']=='bb','C'] = 1  loc returns a true/false for every row and only updates values where the condition is true, eliminating the need to specify the exact index

You can simply use .loc.
df.loc[df['A']=='bb', 'C'] = 1

For me, the main advantage of .at is that it requires the selection to be only one cell, but if you already know that bb is unique, there's no need to go through the extra legwork.

oh my! Thank you!! it was basically that simple. i missed the df wihtin the first []
do you happen to know why this is necessary (besides it does not  work without it :))?

@boopdebop You mean where you wrote 'A'=='bb'? It's because 'A' isn't a dataframe column, it's just a string. 'A'=='bb' → False

i was wondering if you know why this df call is needed 'df['A']=='bb''

I have even been looking in the docs but i only finding now that it is needed, not really why - i guess there is some kind of way to consider why you need to add it .. for me it seems extra - when in the context of loc within the [] i am already in the dataframe, I guess there is some reason it is needed and it probably is confusing me having the different ways of searching in .query

@boopdebop "i am already in the dataframe" - No, that's not a thing in Python. Maybe you're thinking of with() in R, though that works on names (A), not strings ("A").

@wjandrea gave the most idiomatic answer.
However if you have to look for a record using multiple columns, then the following SQL-like style might look bit more readable.
Here is a small demonstration with your DF:
df.loc[df.query("A == 'bb' and B == 1 and D == 1").index, "C"] = 100

versus classical approaches:
df.loc[(df["A"] == "bb") & (df["B"] == 1) & (df["D"] == 1), "C"] = 100

or
df.loc[df["A"].eq("bb") & df["B"].eq(1) & df["D"].eq(1), "C"] = 100

